# assigning NULL to x64 pointers

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

I have a process which is running fine on x86 platforms.
Now I compiled it to x64 and suddenly I cannot assign NULL to my pointers.
If I do something like this:

```
void* pointy = NULL;
```

It will point to 0x0000000100000000
What's going on?

Comment: How are you determining the value?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Is there an error raised?

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. What happens if you just assign `0` to it? I.e. `void* pointy = 0;` BTW, `NULL` is a holdover from C; C++ encourages the use of `0` instead. (`NULL` has to be `0` since there's a lot of code out there like `if(some_ptr)` ...)

Comment: I'm using vs2010, and there aren't any errors.

Comment: @Idov: You said, "it will point to 0x0000000100000000", how do you know that?

Comment: Try nullptr of the new C++11 standard?

Comment: @myrkos: It won't make a difference. `T* x = 0`, `T* x = NULL`, and `T* x = nullptr` all do the same thing.

Comment: @GManNickG: I see it with the debugger.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: I tried it, it didn't help...

Comment: @Idov: Okay, then nothing is wrong. Like my answer says, the value of a pointer set to null is implementation-defined. The value `0` is just convention.

Comment: @Idov: How *exactly* do you see it with the debugger?  Is `0x0000000100000000` the value stored in the pointer object, or the value of the piece of memory it points to?

Comment: In this particular case, the null pointer *is* implementation defined to be all bits zero. We all know that.

Comment: Question: did your program stop working in some way, or were you just surprised by what you saw in the debugger?

Comment: @Mike, where does C++ encourage use of literal zero?

Comment: @BoPersson nonono. NULL has never been defined to be 0, ever. It is never ever ever guaranteed, ever. It *is* guaranteed that if (pointy) will evaluate to a false bool if it is "set to null" or nullptr or however you want to have it

Comment: @ldov - "I see it with the debugger" The most likely explanation is that your debugger is broken or you aren't using it correctly. Unless your code is misbehaving, ignore it and move on. If your code *is* misbehaving, tell us about that.

Comment: @OrgnlDave - *In this specific implementation*, VS2010 on x64 Windows, it **is** defined to be all bits zero. We can skip the "Not defined by the language" part and try to find out what the real problem is.

Comment: @OrgnlDave: `NULL` is a macro and `0` is a valid expansion for `NULL` (as would be `0L` or `0u`). Both `0` and `NULL` are valid _null pointer constants_. A _null pointer constant_ is a constant integer expression with value 0. The type of a _null pointer constant_ is not a pointer type.

Comment: I lack the actual C++ standard, so one of you who ponied up the dough can cross-check. [This is from Bjarne Stroustrup,](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html) the guy who invented C++: "In C++, the definition of NULL is 0, so there is only an aesthetic difference. I prefer to avoid macros, so I use 0. **Another problem with NULL is that people sometimes mistakenly believe that it is different from 0 and/or not an integer.** In pre-standard code, NULL was/is sometimes defined to something unsuitable and therefore had/has to be avoided. That's less common these days."

Answer (score 2):

Null is not necessarily bit-wise zero. Its value is implementation-defined.

---

That is to say, these are all the same:

```
void* pointy = NULL;
void* pointy = 0;
void* pointy = nullptr;
```

They assign a *null-pointer value* to `pointy`. What this value is on a bit-level is completely unspecified, and is not necessarily all bits zero!

If your code is what you say it is, then either: your platform indeed uses that value for null, it doesn't and your compiler is broken, or it doesn't and you're reading the value incorrectly.

In any case, the C++ code is fine, and sets `pointy` to null. No need to worry about anything further.

Comment: @Idov: Do what? If you want a null pointer, just assign it like you have in your post. Don't worry about what value it takes on internally.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: In what way?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I didn't say it wasn't. I said the bit-wise value it takes on isn't necessarily zero.

Comment: @Idov: Do you want a *literal bit-wise value zero* or do you want a null pointer? If the former, do you really know what you're doing with it? If the latter, what you have is working fine.

Comment: I removed the downvote since *theoretically* this is correct, but I doubt it applies in this case. `0x0000000100000000` is most likely not a representation of `NULL`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: If his code is what he says it is, likely or not the pointer is null, and there's nothing more to say. Either his compiler is broken, his platform uses that for null, or he's reading the value wrong.

Comment: @GManNickG then what number would  literal bit-wise zero represent ?

Comment: @keety: Depends on whatever platform you're on. Generally, the moment you start talking about bits you're into implementation-defined territory and your questions become unanswerable in general.

Comment: @keety: pointers are not numbers, so I don't see how that question is relevant. Usually, literal bitwise zero is the number zero (actually guaranteed for unsigned values).

Comment: You can talk about it being unspecified all day, and you're right, but in practice it really needs to be 0 so that code like `if(somePtr)` doesn't break.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFrenanded  pointers are addresses relative or absolute and they are numbers guess what we all intend to say here  is NULL Pointer need not be zero which i agree but Zero for all purposes to me is "literal bitwise zero" atleast i don't know of number representaion where 0x0000000100000000 could represent 0.

Comment: @EdS., the compiler is perfectly capable of converting `if(somePtr)` into `if(somePtr!=magicNullBitPattern)` because it knows `somePtr` is a pointer type.

Comment: @EdS, code like that *won't* break. The compiler knows when a pointer is being tested and correctly generates machine code for testing whether it equals the null pointer value. Just as it knows when a pointer is being assigned and generates code to use the null pointer value.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Ahh, well then... learned something new!  I didn't know the compiler would do that for you.

Comment: @keety: You simply have to stop thinking pointers are integers. They aren't.

Comment: The compiler doesn't literally convert `if(somePtr)` to `if(somePtr!=magicNullBitPattern)`. Instead the pointer to bool conversion is defined in the standard such that null pointer values (whatever the bitwise representation is) convert to false.

Comment: @keety In excess-0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000 is the number 0.

Comment: @bames53, wouldn't `(somePtr!=magicNullBitPattern)` be the conversion to `bool` at some low level?

Comment: Yeah, something has to do that check (or whatever check the platform requires). But as far as the language is concerned all that happens is a conversion to boolean. For example an AST representation of the program wouldn't include that check, just a node representing the pointer to boolean conversion.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a program containing:

```
void* pointy = NULL;
```

it initializes the pointer object `pointy` so it contains a *null pointer* value (assuming that you've `#include`d one of the headers that defines the `NULL` macro).

A *null pointer* is a value of a given pointer type that is distinct from any every other value of that type.  Logically, it's a pointer that doesn't point to anything.

A null pointer can be represented in C++ source code by a *null pointer constant*.  `NULL` is a macro that expands to a null pointer constant.  A literal `0` is also a null pointer constant, as is the keyword `nullptr` (a recent addition to the language).  This does *not* necessarily imply that a null pointer value is represented as all-bits-zero, but it usually is, and I'd be willing to bet that it is on your system.

If you print the value of `pointy`:

```
std::cout << "pointy = " << pointy << "\n";
```

you'll see an implementation-defined representation of a null pointer.  On my system, it prints `pointy = 0`.  On other systems, it might be `0x0`, or `[null]`, or almost anything else, but it should be recognizable as a null pointer.

To test whether the value of `pointy` is a null pointer, compare it in your program:

```
if (pointy == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Yes, it's a null pointer\n");
}
else {
    std::cout << "No, it's not a null pointer (?)\n");
}
```

Note that you cannot dereference `pointy` to determine what it points to, because it's of type `void*`.  If it were of some other pointer type, such as `int*`, then you could write code to dereference it, but the behavior of that code would be undefined; the most likely behavior would be a program crash, but anything is possible.

As for what you're seeing in your debugger, I can't really guess without more information.  It's possible that your debugger is working incorrectly, but that's unlikely.  It's possible that you're looking at what `pointy` points to (probably at memory address 0), but that's also unlikely; since a `void*` pointer doesn't point to data of any specified type, there's no way for the debugger to display it.

Could it be that you've set a breakpoint at the definition of `pointy`, and are looking at the value stored in it when you hit the breakpoint?  If so, perhaps you're simply seeing the value *before* the initialization occurs.  Try stepping ahead one line and looking at the value again.  If this seemed to work correctly on x86, it's probably because the garbage that `pointy` contained before it was initialized happened to look like a null pointer.

In any case, the C++ language says nothing about what you'll see when using a debugger; it only defines the behavior of a program as it's executing.  If you're having trouble using your debugger, that's a legitimate question, but you'll need to tell us what debugger you're using, exactly what you're doing with it, and show us a small complete program that exhibits the problem.

**EDIT :** In a comment on another answer, you wrote

> I want "pointy" to point to 0.

There are at least two very different things that could mean.

This:

```
int* ptr = new int(0);
```

causes `ptr` to point to an object somewhere in memory; that object contains the `int` value `0`.  You could say that "ptr points to 0", but it would be more accurate to say that "ptr points to an object whose value is 0".

This:

```
int *nptr = 0;
```

causes `nptr`'s value to be a *null pointer*.  This is probably what you mean by "points to 0", but it's better to say that `nptr`'s value is a null pointer.  (If you view `nptr` as a machine-level address, it's likely that it contains the address of memory location zero; in other words, `nptr` points to memory location 0.  But in C++ terms, it doesn't really point to any memory location at alll; a null pointer value is a special address-like value used to distinguish pointers that don't point anywhere from pointers that point to objects.)

What you really want, I think, is for `pointy` to contain a null pointer value, and the code you showed us:

```
void* pointy = NULL;  // or 0, or nullptr
```

is exactly the right way to do that.